# Access 2010, insert bold label in ribbon

Tags: xml, vba

Is-it possible to insert bold label in a ribbon Access or change the color or font of some label ?

Excuse my very bad English 
Thank you in advance,
Franck

Answer (score 1):

I double it. I don't see an attribute for font family or font weight. The available attributes for labels are ([from here](http://www.accessribbon.de/en/?Access_-_Ribbons%3aRibbon_XML___Controls%3aLabel) look for the label)

```
enabled
id
idMso
idQ
insertAfterMso
insertAfterQ
insertBeforeMso
insertBeforeQ
label
screentip
showLabel
supertip
tag
visible
```

A full XSD for the ribbon XML can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1574)

Comment: Thank you very much, but I know this link; I don't find an answer to my question :-(

Comment: Id the only acceptable answer is that "there exists a way to make your label bold" then, no, you did not find an answer. But I think the actual answer is that it is not possible to do formatting like that in the ribbon. Have you seen it done before?

Comment: Hello Brad, thank you for your answer. No I have never seen it before.